# Sybase client install fails on Red Hat linux

Tags: installation, sybase, sap-ase, sybase-ase15, dbclient

I have downloaded the SDK for Adaptive Server Enterprise - Linux on x86_64 64bit (sybase version 16.0)
After uploading to a Red Hat Linux machine, RHEL 7.5

Running the install, the installer exits with the error message
"JRE libraries are missing or not not compatible"

The installer unpacks its own version of JRE in /tmp directory
Why would this fail on Red Hat Linux?

I've uploaded the same install package to a Linux machine running Ubuntu 20
It installs successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messages generated by the installer are not always 'useful' and often times are a result of an earlier 'fail' in the installation process.  Without perusing the slew of log messages generated by the installer my only *guesses* (at this point) are a couple possible issues with `/tmp` (the default location where the installer unpacks and invokes a myriad of sub-installers):

- in some OSs the `/tmp` directory (or filesystem) has been configured to disallow running/executing code from `/tmp` (ie, a `noexec` setting has been applied to the `/tmp` filesystem)
- the `/tmp` filesystem filled up during the installer's unpacking of various subpackages

In both cases the (easy) workaround would be to tell the installer to use a different directory in place of `/tmp`.  This would consist of setting the `IATEMPDIR` variable before running the installer, eg:

```
$ export IATEMPDIR='/some/other/dir'
$ ./setup.bin
```

Where you insure:

- your linux login has read/write permissions to `/some/other/dir`
- the underlying filesystem has enough free space (2x-3x the size of the installation package)
- your chosen directory is not a sub-directory of `/tmp`

If this workaround (setting `IATEMPDIR`) does not address the issue then the next step would be to peruse the various log files looking for an 'earlier' issue/error/failure that could shine a light on the issue.